# Flutter: How to refresh all ViewModels when a common property of service that that they're accessing has changed ? (MVVM Architecture)

Tags: flutter, mvvm, stack, provider

Let's assume that, header, footer, drawer, body widget have their own indiviual viewmodels and they are all accessing UserService and displays the user's name.
What if the user's name has changed? how to refresh all viewmodels?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a state management solution :

[Introduction to state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro)

[List of state management approaches](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

I personally recommend [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/), Provider or BLoC.